problemas con local storage angular
Buenas a todos estoy armando una aplicación con angular en la que estoy haciendo un login y quiero proteger las rutas con un guard.
en el guard tengo el siguiente código:
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivateFn, Router } from '@angular/router';

export const authGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {

  const router = inject(Router)

  if(!!localStorage.getItem('token')){
    return true
  }else{
    router.navigateByUrl('/login')
    return false
  }
};


y luego en el router lo llamo de la siguiente manera:
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component:HomeComponent},
  {path:'home', component:HomeComponent},
  {path: 'admin', component:AdminComponent,canActivate: [authGuard]},
  {path: 'ligas', component:AdminLigasComponent},
  {path: 'login', component:LoginComponent},

];

La aplicación funciona bien y responde como tiene que responder, pero en la consola de vs estudio me da el siguiente error:
ERROR ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
    at authGuard (C:\apps\Shorti\shortiweb\src\app\guards\auth.guard.ts:9:3)
    at eval (C:\apps\Shorti\shortiweb\node_modules\@angular\router\fesm2022\router.mjs:3375:134)
    at Module.runInInjectionContext (C:\apps\Shorti\shortiweb\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2022\core.mjs:3400:16)
    at eval (C:\apps\Shorti\shortiweb\node_modules\@angular\router\fesm2022\router.mjs:3375:89)
    at _Observable.eval (C:\apps\Shorti\shortiweb\node_modules\rxjs\dist\esm\internal\observable\defer.js:5:19)
    at _Observable._trySubscribe (C:\apps\Shorti\shortiweb\node_modules\rxjs\dist\esm\internal\Observable.js:37:25)
    at eval (C:\apps\Shorti\shortiweb\node_modules\rxjs\dist\esm\internal\Observable.js:31:30)
    at errorContext (C:\apps\Shorti\shortiweb\node_modules\rxjs\dist\esm\internal\util\errorContext.js:19:9)
    at _Observable.subscribe (C:\apps\Shorti\shortiweb\node_modules\rxjs\dist\esm\internal\Observable.js:22:9)
    at eval (C:\apps\Shorti\shortiweb\node_modules\rxjs\dist\esm\internal\operators\take.js:10:20)

y no entiendo qué es lo que pasa, ni cómo solucionarlo.

Qué versión de Angular estas usando?

la version es angular 17

Ese error es porque localStorage no está disponible durante la renderización en el lado del servidor (SSR).
Solución: asegúrate de que localStorage solo se acceda en el navegador, agregando una verificación.
if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && !!localStorage.getItem('token')) {
  return true;
}


funciono correctamente, muchas gracias
